# Javascript string replace function on matched group

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use

```
"string".replace(regex, myFunction('$1'));
```

Where myFunction takes the matched string as a parameter and does different things based on what is contains and returns a different string.  I've found that this just passes in the '$1' string instead of what it represents.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: mhodges Awesome, I totally missed this in my lookover.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close, just change `myFunction` slightly so it expects *two* arguments; the second will be the content of the capture group. Then do this:

```
var result = "string".replace(regex, myFunction);
```

Or if you can't change `myFunction`, do this:

```
var result = "string".replace(regex, function(m, c0) {
    return myFunction(c0);
});
```

Note that in both cases, we're passing a function reference as the second argument to `replace`, we're not directly *calling* the function. When you give `replace` a function in the second argument, it calls it, passing the full regex match as the first argument, and then any capture group matches as subsequent arguments.

Live Examples:

```js
var rex = /test (.*)/;

// Changing myFunction to expect two args:
function myFunction1(m, c0) {
  return c0.toUpperCase();
}
console.log("test one".replace(rex, myFunction1));

// Leaving myFunction alone and wrapping the call to it:
function myFunction2(c0) {
  return c0.toUpperCase();
}
console.log("test two".replace(rex, function(m, c0) {
  return myFunction2(c0);
}));
```